# Reduce animations code repetition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an array of div animations and that produced a lot of repetitive code.

For instance :

```
$('#elem a:eq(0)').addClass("hiddenCSS").viewportChecker({
    classToRemove: 'hiddenCSS',
    classToAdd: 'animated bounceInLeft',
    offset: 200
});

$('#elem a:eq(1)').addClass("hiddenCSS").viewportChecker({
    classToRemove: 'hiddenCSS',
    classToAdd: 'animated bounceInUp',
    offset: 400
});
```

That's only two elements, but what if I have dozens ? My code becomes unusable very fast.

I wanted to create a function to make things easier but it is not working. Now I wonder if I'm supposed to create a class with a specific method.
This is what I tried, doesn't work and is undefined :

```
function animation(elem,animation,offset) {
    $(elem).addClass("hiddenCSS").viewportChecker({
        classToRemove: 'hiddenCSS',
        classToAdd: 'animated' + animation,
        offset: offset
    });
}

animation('#elem a:eq(1)', 'bounceIn', 200);
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work. What does the console say?

Comment: it says "animation is not defined"

Comment: Then there is likely a typo elsewhere

Comment: you're right, I forgot the space in classToAdd ( `classToAdd: 'animated' + ' ' + animation` ). Now the animation works on load, but if I write it in the console, it still says the function is not defined

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you mean? If you write it in the console?

Comment: Try to wrap your function call in a `$(document).ready`. I don't see a typo either: `$(document).ready(function() {animation('#elem a:eq(1)', 'bounceIn', 200); });`

Comment: if I write "animation('#elem a:eq(1)', 'bounceIn', 200);"

Comment: Is the function nested inside the $(function() {.........});  perhaps? If so, move it outside

Comment: yes it's in $(document).ready(function() {});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a function inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function myFunction() {}
  myFunction();
)};
```

it will NOT be globally available.

Move it outside

```
function myFunction() {}

$(document).ready(function() {
   myFunction();
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work with a document ready. It seems that your function declaration is not stacked before executing `animation(...)`

```
function animation(elem,animation,offset) {
    $(elem).addClass("hiddenCSS").viewportChecker({
        classToRemove: 'hiddenCSS',
        classToAdd: 'animated' + animation,
        offset: offset
    });
}

// $(function(){
// or more readable
$(document).ready(function() {    
    animation('#elem a:eq(1)', 'bounceIn', 200);
});
```

Comment: As I commented while discussing with OP

Comment: Yes, after my comment :) nice behaviour @mplungjan

Comment: What behaviour? I believe my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668205/reduce-animations-code-repetition-in-jquery/33668529#comment55109794_33668205 was the answer - not to wrap in document.ready which it obviously was already

Comment: or this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668205/reduce-animations-code-repetition-in-jquery/33668529#comment55109719_33668205 . that is kids play :)

Comment: I fail to see what you mean. Your comment suggested to wrap his calls in document.ready - his problem was that ALL his code including the function declaration was inside the document.ready.